# About Distance Thrower feat, still confused?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> **Distance Thrower (Combat)** (From d20PFSRD)
>
> You are accurate with thrown weapons at longer ranges than normal.
>
> Prerequisite: Str 13.
>
> Benefit: With a thrown weapon, you reduce your penalty on ranged attack rolls due to range by 2.

I understand the thrown weapons have range increments up to 5x the weapons range.
EX: Dagger 10 feet max range 50 feet at -8 to attack roll

You get a -2 penalty for trying to reach a target beyond the first range increment
EX: Dagger 20 feet at -2 to attack roll

Is Distance Thrower's penalty reduction for the first range increment that you are penalized?

EX: Dagger with Distance Thrower feat

- Dagger 10 feet with Distance Thrower no pen
- Dagger 20 feet with Distance Thrower no pen
- Dagger 30 feet with Distance Thrower -2
- Dagger 40 feet with Distance Thrower -4
- Dagger 50 feet with Distance Thrower -6

Or is the penalty reduction per range increment?

Thus Dagger can be thrown 50 feet at no penalty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally thrown weapons can be thrown upto 5 range increments with -2 for each one past the initial. So thats 0 (0-20 feet)/-2 (21-40 feet)/-4 (41-60 feet)/-6 (61-80 feet)/-8 (81-100 feet).

The feat changes that to 0/0/-2/-4/-6.